# Azure Logic apps PDF4Me Connector to convert PDF to images

Tags: azure, pdf, azure-logic-apps

I am using the PDF4Me connector in Logic apps to convert the PDF to thumbnail images. I am getting the response code as 204 but I am not getting the file name  and the content length is zero. Below is the response. Is there a way to get the output files from here  ?

```
{
    "statusCode": 204,
    "headers": {
        "Timing-Allow-Origin": "*",
        "x-ms-apihub-cached-response": "true",
        "Date": "Sun, 09 Aug 2020 21:22:32 GMT",
        "Content-Length": "0"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For getting the output files, you can add an action named "Create Blob" to restore the file content of Thumbnail Connector, and then you can download the blob from Azure Storage.

But refer to document, the content of the Image or Thumbnail will be binary, which means it would not show as a picture. Reference: [enter link description here](https://developer.pdf4me.com/docs/api/microsoft-flow/create-thumbnail-flow-connector/)

**For Logic Apps**, it looks like this:
[image]

**For output content type:**
[image]

Check the output file type in **Blob Storage container**: `Content-Type:application/octet-stream` means `binary`
[image]

Comment: size is 0b which essentially a blank page has been produced; Correct me if I am wrong